# In fastapi, how to return data in chunks

Tags: python, streaming, fastapi

I have a fastapi based service in python. I have a simple requirement: I have an end-point that does a lot of processing in the back-end, but has intermediate results. I want to return data in chunks. I am able to get my code to work if the return data is a string/byte-string. But if I want to return a json structure, I am just unable to make it work. Here's a simple code-snippet that I have tried. If i replace yield data with yield f"{json.dumps(data)}" I get the expected result, but the response data comes as a json string, which is not what I want.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here? Have consulted all kinds of sources with no success.

```
@app.get("/experimental/stream", summary="Experimenting with some streaming response stuff") async def stream_response():
async def stream_generator():
   for i in range(10):
       data = {
           "iteration": i
       }
       yield data
       time.sleep(1)
   return(StreamingResponse(stream_generator(), media_type="application/json"))
```

Comment: You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) helpful